# How do I welcome someone in Latin?

Tags: idiom, word-request, modern-life

When someone comes to visit me at my *villa*, I would like to greet them and welcome them in. I know how to welcome English ("welcome"), German ("wilkommen"), and French ("bienvenue") guests in a single word. But if a native Roman comes to visit me, what should I say to him?

Comment: Have a look here: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IU_zCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&lpg=PA278&dq=%22bene+venisti%22&source=bl&ots=PT0aCmMfiJ&sig=S3wIcEADdDVrVBF40nKG1yPKx6o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5r6nehYLXAhUMU1AKHdryB-YQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22bene%20venisti%22&f=false

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pekkanen's dictionary suggests *salve advenis/advenitis* or *bene adveneris/adveneritis*, but I found no classical attestations of these.
These are understandable phrases, but I don't know how canonical they are.

I dug around and found some relevant phrases in the literature that you might want to build on:

- Plautus, *Trinummus*, 1097: *et salve et salvom te advenisse gaudeo*
- Pacuvius, *Tragoediae*, 232: *expectata advenis: salue, hospita!*
- Plautus, *Bacchides*, 101 (accepting a welcome, but can be turned around for a welcoming idiom): *Bene me accipies advenientem, mea soror.*
- Cicero, *De republica*, 1.18 (on how someone was happy to welcome someone): *eorum adventus periucundus et pergratus fuisset*
- Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum*, 4.19.1 (on arrival of a letter, but works also for arrival of a person): *O exspectatas mihi tuas litteras! O gratum adventum!*

It seems that if you want a simple everyday "welcome", then *salve(te)* is a good choice.
If you want more flavor, use or adapt any of the quotes above.