# I'll put the kettle on

Tags: idiom, motto

[Disclaimer: I know no Latin, and am asking from a position of ignorance; please feel free to correct any assumptions you spot!]

My sister recently pondered what our family motto would be, if we had one. I suggested "I'll put the kettle on." (We know the Morgan family has several mottoes commonly ascribed to it, but I'm ignoring that for the sake of this question!)

Family mottoes often use dog Latin, so I could easily just go with something like "Lebetem coques" (schoolboy smirk) or "Semper ferventi ab ollae" or "poppus kettleus onnus" and call it done. But now I've started digging, I can't help but wonder how the same greeting would have been given in Latin... or would be given today, in those communities which still use it.

---

**Figurative**

Here, auto-translation won't help. This is something that I think only people steeped in Latin culture would know.

The phrase "put the kettle on" is an English Idiom, celebrated in verse (eg "Polly put the kettle on...") for at least a couple of hundred years. It carries a HUGE weight of subtext in some areas of England, which I only really appreciated after moving to Texas, where it's taken literally.

The similar-appearing phrase "I'll boil the kettle" means "I will make some boiled water", with no implied promise to take that task any further.

But in England at least, "I'll put the kettle on" translates to "Unless you decline, I commit to making us some warm beverages, and to spending at least enough time with you for us to finish the drinks. There may be Hobnobs, and dunking is encouraged." It is both a warm welcome and an invitation to stay awhile. A passive-affectionate version of "come on in, grab a cold one".

So, after greeting a welcome guest at the door, how would someone make them feel at home, *in Latin*? "Let's break bread together"? "Take a load off, make yourself at home?" "Here, let me take your coat"?

This is covered a little under [How do I welcome someone in Latin?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/5451/how-do-i-welcome-someone-in-latin) -- the answer by Joonas Ilmaverta is rather excellent, but "I'll put the kettle on" comes *after* that initial welcoming phrase, and fulfills the "making-at-home, settling-in" part of the conversation.

If such a term exists, how would it vary depending on region and era?

It's possible there's no equivalent term, though, even in neologistic Latin. In which case, I'd have to fall back on a literal translation.

---

**Literal**

As a non-grammatical idiom, I suspect it is not easily auto-translated. Google Translate suggests "Lebetem pone", which sounds great in my head, but feels like it must be a literal translation into a gibberish sentence fragment, making little sense in Latin: Put the cauldron? Stuff the pot?

The missing part of the sentence is ambiguous. Put it on the stove? Put it "on the boil" (another idiom)? Turn the power on? Each of these, I imagine, would be translated differently, and I suspect the meaning has drifted through the three over time.

Translating "boil the kettle" might be easier, but it's another idiom (kettles don't boil, the water in them does), but it's the kind of synecdoche that could be near-universal. But I'm not sure Latin has a term specifically for boiling water, as opposed to cooking something. Again, Google translate for "boil water" suggests "Aquam coquite," but translates coquite to "cook". And "boil the kettle" to "coques lebetem"... cook the pot? Can that be right?

And I'm not even sure Latin has a specific term for "Kettle" (=a container for boiling beverage-water), distinct from a mere "stew-pot" - Google suggests *lebetum*, *cortina*, *lebes*, *ahenum*, *ollae*, and more, but I'm unconvinced. Most other online sources I checked suggest *ollae*.

So even a literal translation seems non-trivial.

---

**Motto**

There may be patterns of usage that are used in mottoes for brevity (like headlines in English), which I'd also be unaware of: I've been unable to find anything saying so in a brief search, but I'm interested if so.

Comment: I think offering a drink really bridges both sides of the Atlantic. "Would you care for a cup of coffee" when coming to someone's home has the same ring (although if it's at evening asking "can I get you a drink" instead is more normal). I don't know the exact wording, but offering food is very common in Russia and Ukraine (as well as offering a drink). I'm not immediately sure if we know an idiom for it in ancient Rome, but maybe someone will be able to find something suitable. You might have a few options.